# Is there a way to add "Virtual" Row in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What I mean by "virtual" is the following:

For example, you have the following table,

```
Name | Age | Id
John | 22  | 01
Alen | 18  | 02
```

And when you run the following query:

```
SELECT name, age, id, "no value" as noVal
FROM Users
```

it returns the new table by adding "virtual" column

```
Name | Age | Id | noVal
John | 22  | 01 | no value
Alen | 18  | 02 | no value
```

My question is, is there a way to add a new "virtual" row, I mean without actually modifying the table or using the `INSERT` statement. I think the code should go inside the `SELECT` statement.
So for example after adding a new "virtual" row I get the following table:

```
Name | Age | Id
John | 22  | 01
Alen | 18  | 02
Alex | 25  | 03
```

Or I can have 'null' values for the new "virtual" row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your second question about 'copy one of the existing rows to the "virtual" row':

```
SELECT name, age, id
FROM Users
UNION ALL
SELECT name, age, id
FROM Users
WHERE id = '01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view:

```
create view v_users as
    select name, age, id
    from users
    union all
    select 'Alex', 25, '03';
```

Or just use `union all` when you query the table.

Comment: I tried to create a view, however, it did not seem to work. Then I used ```union all``` when querying the table. It worked but I got another question:
Here is what I wrote:
```SELECT name, age, id FROM users
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Alex', 25, '03'
```
Now I would like to know is there a way to link the newly created "virtual" row to other row's values. In other words to copy one of the existing rows to the "virtual" row

Comment: @Grig . . . You would need to insert the row into the table if you want it to always be there.  I'm not sure what the issue is with the view.  BigQuery definitely supports views.